# Closing a view class and opening another view class

Tags: java, android

I call a view class from my activity. Then the view class calls the same activity. Here is the problem, once the activity comes back up, it won't register any more button pushes.(I'm trying to call another view class. Here is some code:

View Class

```
public class AnimationView extends View {

    Activity myActivity;
    //...
    public AnimationView(Context context, Activity activity) {
    super(context);
    //...
    }
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //...
    myActivity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }
}
```

Home Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AnimationView mDrawViewA;
///...
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    mDrawViewA = new AnimationView(this,this);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    //...
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //...
        setContentView(mDrawViewA);
        //calls more views 
        //......
    });
}
```

I realize now maybe I should have been calling the view classes in different activities, but I would very much like a get all the view classes working within the same activity.

Comment: I forgot to say in my view class constructor is: myActivity = activity;

Comment: You ideally should not be storing an Activity reference anywhere. Also an Activity already is a Context object

Comment: If you need to dynamically swap content, that's what Fragments are for

Comment: So would i have x fragments for the amount of view animations, and just call the viewclasses in each fragment?

Comment: @bluesheepllama no, one single fragment can handle that. Fragments are, as the name suggests, fragments of user interfaces with their own specific behaviour. Since your question is about adding views to the activity's root layout, I posted an answer that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling `setContentView` every time you press the "start" button. This method will overwrite the current layout (if any) with the new value you're setting.

What you can do to get the result you're expecting, which, from what I understand, is to add a new `AnimationView` to your current layout on every button click, you can try something like this:

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AnimationView animationView = new AnimationView(getApplicationContext());

        // I'm using ConstraintLayout as an example, since I don't know exactly what layout you're using
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Set the layout params the way you want

        addContentView(animationView, params); // This is where the magic happens
    }
});
```

In short, `addContentView` is the method you should use when you want to add new views into your activity's root layout.

PS.: It's a terribly bad practice to let the views "know" the activity controlling it. It's always the opposite way around: the activity/fragment knows the view(s) it's controlling.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like how you can change the size of the view. How do you close the view once the animation finishes? This was the way that was shown to me:     myActivity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

Comment: In OOP it's totally acceptable for a higher level object to have references to lower level objects, but never the opposite way around. So the responsibility of adding views to the activity should belong to no one other than the activity itself. BTW if my answer solves your problem, please accept it as an answer to this question